How do I change the color of a rectangle I have already drawn in Python3 Kivy?
I'm trying to understand how to use Kivy - specifically, the canvas. I have more or less understood how to move around and resize a rectangle I've already drawn, but I can't get the rectangle to change color. Here is my code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color


class CanvasWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CanvasWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.click_occured = False
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0)
            self.background = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            self.rect1 = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width/2, self.height/2))
            Color(0, 0, 1)
            self.rect2 = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width/4, self.height/4))
            self.bind(pos = self.update_rect, size = self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.background.pos = self.pos
        self.background.size = self.size
        if not self.click_occured:
            self.rect1.pos = self.pos
        else:
            self.rect1.pos = self.x + self.width/8, self.y + self.height/8
        self.rect1.size = (self.width/2, self.height/2)
        self.rect2.pos = self.pos
        self.rect2.size = (self.width/4, self.height/4)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.click_occured = True
        self.rect1.pos = self.x + self.width/8, self.y + self.height/8
        #also, change rect1's color from white to red


class CanvasApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CanvasWidget()
CanvasApp().run()

In place of the comment at the end of the on_touch_down method, I would like to change rect1's color to red. It has to be a change to the existing rectangle and not the creation of a new one since I want it to remain behind rect2 and I don't want to manually redraw the latter.
If possible, I would like to achieve that without using the kv language since I want to be able to create rectangles, labels etc. on the fly while the code is running, and that seems to be inconvenient with the kv language.

An even simpler way without using groups is to just modify the rgb of the Color. First save a reference to the Color in your __init__() method by replacing:
Color(1, 1, 1)

with:
self.color1 = Color(1, 1, 1)

Then, in your on_touch_down() method, add the line:
    self.color1.rgb = (1, 0, 0)

See the documentation.

You can use the graphics InstructionGroup to accomplish what you want. First, create an InstructionGroup for canvas instructions involved, like this:
    # create an instruction group for the white Rectangle
    self.grp1 = InstructionGroup()
    self.grp1.add(Color(1, 1, 1))
    self.rect1 = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width/2, self.height/2))
    self.grp1.add(self.rect1)

And add that group to the canvas with self.canvas.add(self.grp1).
Then you can modify that group by removing/adding instructions:
    self.grp1.remove(self.grp1.children[0])  # remove the color instruction
    self.grp1.insert(0, Color(1, 0, 0))  # insert the new color

Here is a modified version of your code that uses this approach:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, InstructionGroup


class CanvasWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CanvasWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.click_occured = False

        # create an instruction group for the white Rectangle
        self.grp1 = InstructionGroup()
        self.grp1.add(Color(1, 1, 1))
        self.rect1 = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width/2, self.height/2))
        self.grp1.add(self.rect1)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0)
            self.background = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.canvas.add(self.grp1)  # add the instruction group to the canvas
            Color(0, 0, 1)
            self.rect2 = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width/4, self.height/4))
            self.bind(pos = self.update_rect, size = self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.background.pos = self.pos
        self.background.size = self.size
        if not self.click_occured:
            self.rect1.pos = self.pos
        else:
            self.rect1.pos = self.x + self.width/8, self.y + self.height/8
        self.rect1.size = (self.width/2, self.height/2)
        self.rect2.pos = self.pos
        self.rect2.size = (self.width/4, self.height/4)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.click_occured = True
        self.grp1.remove(self.grp1.children[0])  # remove the color instruction
        self.grp1.insert(0, Color(1, 0, 0))  # insert the new color
        self.rect1.pos = self.x + self.width/8, self.y + self.height/8
        #also, change rect1's color from white to red


class CanvasApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CanvasWidget()
CanvasApp().run()

